# Simple inorder tree traversal giving a non terminating loop. (using arrays)

Tags: c, binary-tree, infinite-loop

Following is my code for building a simple tree. The approach I'm using here is that if a particular node is at index n in the arr[] array, then it has it's left child at index 2*n+1 and right child at 2*n+2 in the same arr[] array. And then I'm doing an inorder traversal. However, I'm getting an infinite loop at node D as my output. Would love if anybody could help me out here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct node
{
   struct node * lc;
   char data;
   struct node * rc;
};

char arr[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','\0','\0','H','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'};
struct node * root = NULL;

struct node * buildTree(int rootIndex)
{
    struct node * temp = NULL;

    if(arr[rootIndex]!='\0')
    {
            temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->lc = buildTree(rootIndex * 2 + 1);
            temp->data = arr[rootIndex];
            temp->rc = buildTree(rootIndex * 2 + 2);
    }

    return temp;
}

void inorder(struct node * parent)
{
    while(parent != NULL)
    {
        inorder(parent->lc);
        printf("%c\t",parent->data);
        inorder(parent->rc);
    }
}

int main()
{
    root = buildTree(0);
    inorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For questions like that you should be asking help from a debugger, not this website

Comment: 1)`while(parent != NULL)` --> `if(parent != NULL)`

Comment: Oh, well that's embarrassing. Thank you though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like BLUEPIXY mentioned in comments, you need to replace the `while` in `inorder()` method with an `if`. When building tree, D forms the left-most child. Therefore during in-order traversal, D is encountered as the first node to be printed. But the while loop keeps printing it as the condition never becomes false.

I'm sure a tool like `gdb` would have done much better job in explaining this.

Comment: Thank you, got the problem. I'm using CodeBlocks.

Comment: I meant gdb not gcc. Corrected it above :) From Wikipedia page CodeBlocks debugger doesn't look bad either.